# Carrying user inputs across sessions in Shiny Apps

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I have been trying for some time to find the answer to this, and have seen many helpful results. However, they are all larger in scale than I am interested in.

What I'd like to know is, is there a way to store user inputs across sessions in Shiny apps?

For example, I built an automated, independent application that runs highly-customizable projections for time-series sales data, but each time the user starts the app, they must fill in each of the input fields, i.e. which variable to forecast, which to filter by, initial forecast periods, etc. I'm just looking for a way to store their inputs as variables to be called when they restart the app at a later time.

Just simple character & numeric values. Isn't there a simple way to do this, outside of writing a new, external log file with the inputs and calling them that way?

Comment: How do you plan to deploy your Shiny app: locally or in a server?

Comment: Right, sorry, locally. I'd ideally like to package it as an executable file using portable versions of R and Chrome that users can run locally. I understand that accomplishing the above will be either expensive or difficult if deployed on a server.

Comment: You have seen those articles: 
http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/share-data.html
http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html
Which seems to address your problem.