# R Shiny - Independent selectinput dropdown for different tabpanels

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I'm new to shiny and tried hours and hours on the below but couldn't !!!

I have a "selectinput" dropdown and 3 tabpanels. The dropdown list for 3 tabpanels are different and somehow with you expert's help managed to make them reactive.

The issue I'm facing is, I selected an option "X"  in tabpanel 1's dropdown and then moving to tabpanel 2 and selecting option "A" there. When I move back to tabpanel1 the option "X" is gone and the dropdown is blank as there is no "X" in the list of tabpanel 2's dropdown.

Could anyone please help me solve this issue?

Simplified script of what I tried:

```
selectInput(inputId = 'selected.indicator', NULL, choices = c('')),

#######

tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("tabPanel1", value = 'tab1', tableOutput("table1")),
        tabPanel("tabPanel2", value = 'tab2', DT::dataTableOutput("table2"), downloadButton(outputId = "download", label = "Download Table")),
        tabPanel("tabPanel3", value = 'tab3', DT::dataTableOutput("table3")),
        id ="tabselected"
      )

#######

choices = reactiveValues(
    tab1 = table1$column1,
    tab2 = table2$column1,
    tab3 = table3$column1
  )

#######

observeEvent(input$tabselected, {
    
    updateSelectInput(session, 'selected.indicator', choices = choices[[input$tabselected]])
    #output$lastselection = renderText(input$selected.indicator)
  })
```

Comment: I think my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63183085/can-i-maintain-input-defaults-across-different-instances-of-a-shiny-app-module/63188283#63188283) will help you.

Comment: Thank you Limey for your help. Somehow I managed to solve this by passing on values to the global variables and working fine now...